# how to stop and resume game with handler class?

Tags: android

i want to pause the game and then continue from the same point but i can stop the game but when i continue it.
activity will crash

```
 private void stopRunning()
{
    mMyPlayFieldView.invalidatePlayfield();
    mInputHandler.removeCallbacks(this);
}





@Override

protected void onPause()
{

stopRunning();
super.onPause();

}
```

Comment: You still didn't post the stacktrace from the crash

Comment: i just call this mInputHandler.post(this); on continue button